# Exporting OptiTrack camera captures as jpeg

Tags: export

In the Motive software for OptiTrack, .tak (take) files are generated which contain the motion capture data.

Is there a way to export the individual camera frames as jpeg images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot export frame by frame as jpeg, see: https://forums.naturalpoint.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=15509&p=65604&hilit=kimtae55#p65604

But you can export the video and turn that into frames using ffmpeg.